# Disabling Sideloading in Developer Features on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, uwp, sideloading

We have built a Windows 10 UWP app and have packaged it through Visual Studio as a Sideloaded app. The packages will be deployed on to user's machines by running powershell scripts. We are hoping to disable Sideloading in Developer features once the app has been deployed. However there isn't enough documentation available to see if a sideloaded app will work as usual or cause any errors in future once the sideloading in developer features for the machine has been turned off? Is there a way to safely achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

The sideloaded app still is UWP app. Once the app installed successfully, disabling 'Sideload apps' in developer will not affect the installed apps. You needn't worry.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Will this cause any certificate errors or issues with auto updates? The initial tests did not return many errors, however there is a concern that disabling side loading can cause issues in the long run probably when certificate has reached the expiry date?